# Cleaner (nested) closure in JavaScript with jQuery's each()

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, closures

I was wondering if there is a cleaner (more succinct)  way to do what `each()` is doing in following JavaScript code.

```
$(".moreinfodialog")
    .before('<a href="#">Click for more info.</a>')
    .each(function() {
        var temp = this;
        $(this).prev("a").click(function() {
            $(temp).dialog("open");
            return false;
        });
    })
    .dialog({ autoOpen: false, modal: true });
```

Note that the last call re-orders the dom elements, so `.moreinfodialog` classes are not next to the hrefs any more.

BTW: this source uses jquery/jquery-ui dialog to hide any text in a div with the `.moreinfodialog` class, and replace it with the `Click for more info.` text.  When that text is clicked, a dialog with the text inside the original div is displayed.

Comment: I think you can't really make it shorter, but it would look cleaner if you separated before() from each() and dialog()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit:**  This answer was relevant in older versions of jQuery.  In newer version `$.map` works differently.

Check out the [$.map()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) function, used to perform the same operation on every element of an array.

```
$('.moreinfodialog').map(function(idx, element) {
    $(this).prev("a").click(function() {
            $(element).dialog("open");
            return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I pasted that in on accident.  The callback function gets passed two parameters, the array key and the array item.  So `this` and `element` are pointing to the same thing in this case.  Hope that helps.

Comment: And I think he means .each() instead of .map()
http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.map

Comment: Map() is a good idea, but if you want to use chaining as I do in my code, you must "return this" from the map function.  So in the end, the code is the same length, but a little less efficient since we are now doing map() on the original array. (not that I care)

Comment: please use preventDefault() and not return false.

Comment: -1 Woh $.each is used to perform the same operation on every element of an array. $.map is used to _map_ one array to another.